# Conditionally disable validation for embedded form

Tags: symfony

I have an embedded form (for `Address`) which has its own validations for various properties. I embed this form in a parent form (for `Person`), and I have a checkbox on the parent form that says something like "Person has an address?"

When the checkbox is left unchecked, I want to disable all the validation for the embedded `Address` form. Or, better yet, if I can just remove the embedded form from being submitted completely that would be OK too.

I looked at using validation groups, but the use case doesn't match my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, figured this out. When adding the `AddressType` embedded form in my form builder, I just pass in the option for validation groups like so:

```
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $form->add('address', new AddressType(), array(
            'label' => 'Address',
            'validation_groups' => function (FormInterface $form) {
                if ($form->getParent()->get('toggleAddress')->getData() === false) {
                    return array();
                }
                return array('Default');
            }
        ));
    });
```

Within the validation group function, a check is made to see if the toggle to enable Address is off. If so, return a blank array, with removes all validation groups, including the "Default" one.

Answer (score 0):

You try to fix your issue with validation group which will not cover your use case (it can but it will be tricky because en empty `Address` object will be linked to your `Person` object).

Basically, you embed your `Address` form everytime whereas it should only be embed when the checkbox is checked. IMHO, you should rely on dynamic form as explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#how-to-dynamically-generate-forms-based-on-user-data).

With this solution, you will need extra JS code in order to update you form when you click the checkbox in order to update the whole form accordingly. Then, there will be no issue about validation because the Address object will only be created when the form is embed.

Additionally (just for information), you can add/edit validation groups according to the submitted data as explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#groups-based-on-the-submitted-data).

Hope my answer is helpfull!

Comment: Yeah I was hoping to not have to conditionally ADD the embedded form if possible. I like showing the form to the user but having the fields grayed out. I'll consider this approach though

Comment: In this case, you should mix my two propositions. Rely on dynamic validation group based on submitted datas for the validation part and generate the embed form as disabled in order to disable it on the backend and so, not consider submitted data if it is disabled. Anyway, you will need to update the underlying object to remove the empty address object if it is disabled (probably needed due to database restriction). All I expose to you can be achieve by events in the form component.